# Adding github libraries to python requirements file

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

How can I add libraries in `requirements.txt`? For example `jenks` library is installable like this:

```
pip install -e "git+https://github.com/perrygeo/jenks.git#egg=jenks"
```

However, if I just write `jenks` in `requirements.txt`, then `pip` is not able to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it to your `requirements.txt` like this:

```
-e git://github.com/perrygeo/jenks.git#egg=jenks
```

See [Git Support](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/?highlight=requirements%20format#git) for details.